# Internal Server Error 500 in $.post jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

My Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cat").change(function(e){
      $.post($("#cat").val(), function(html){
        $("#data").html(html);
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
```

My Html code:

```
<select name="cat" id="cat">
  <option value="http://option1.html">Option 1</option>
  <option value="http://option2.html">Option 2</option>
</select>
<div id="data">Hello World!</div>
```

But when i change selectbox to call ajax, I got Internal Server Error 500, please help me to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get the contents of these html files, you should use $.get()

Like

```
$.get('out1.html')
  .done(function(data){
    $('#data').html(data);
  });
```